# Android admob and Adwhirl integration

Tags: android, admob, adwhirl

I am trying to add addwhirl in my app but I doesnt show up any ads, I am doing following things

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.liverpool.activities"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layout_ad" />
```

in code I am doing following

```
try
    {
        AdManager.setTestDevices(new String[] { AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR });
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_ad);
        AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = new AdWhirlLayout(this, "SDK key from adwhirl");
        Display d = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adWhirlLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(d.getWidth(), 72);
        layout.addView(adWhirlLayout, adWhirlLayoutParams);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
```

where I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you added SDK key from adwhirl

Comment: I had already solved that problem its quite an old question by the way

Comment: If your problem is solved then you shold post answer yourself so others can refer that in future.

Comment: @Vikas Thanks for reminding me, now I had answered the question myself

Comment: I followed as you given above.Could you please tell me how to configured the adwhirl page with ads provider settings. I am new to integrate adwril with android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the above code.

Problem is that I haven't configured the adwhirl page with ads provider settings its very fool to miss such thing

Comment: So, AdWhirl just adds AdMob to your AdWhirlLayout automatically? What's the purpose of the AdManager?

Comment: Purpose of adamanger is that you will be able to serve ads from more providers other than admob only

Answer (score 2):

Remember you only really need the INTERNET permission. The rest is optional. You shouldn't ask for GPS location unless your app needs it. If you do it just for the ads you'll get negative reactions from your users. And trust me adding more geo targeting will not increase your revenue.